# Deployments to Pivotal CloudFoundry installation with a self-signed certificate

Tags: cloud-foundry

We have a test installation of Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

It has a self-signed certificate, so I have not been able to use the cloud foundry maven plugin to perform uploads. Instead, I have been trying to use cloudfoundry-client-lib java client.

cloudfoundry-client-lib has a setting to ignore self-signed certificates, so I am able to log in to our PCF installation with it and perform passive operations, such as listing applications. However, uploads are failing.

I'm trying to upload a 23M zipped Spring Boot app jar. (Also tried it as a jar.) The same application itself has successfully been pushed previously to our PCF installation via 'cf push' . Installing cf-cli is not an option from our Jenkins box.

Uploads result either in a "connection reset by peer" or a broken pipe error.

Has anybody been able to upload or push to a PCF installation that's using a self-signed certificate ?

Code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String target = "api.sys.dev.##.##.##.com";
        String user = "me";
        String password = "secret";
        String uploadFilePath = "./myapp.zip";


        CloudCredentials credentials = new CloudCredentials(user, password);

        java.net.URL URL = new java.net.URL(target);
        CloudFoundryClient client = new CloudFoundryClient(credentials, URL, true);

        File archiveFile = new File(uploadFilePath);

        client.uploadApplication("myappname", uploadFilePath, new FileInputStream(archiveFile),
                new uploadCallback(logger) );

        client.logout();
}
```

dependency section from pom:

```
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
     <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-lib</artifactId>
     <version>RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: As a follow up, below are the options I tried with the maven cloudfoundry plugin to work around the certificate problem. They had no effect: -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.allowall=true -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.ignore.validity.dates=true

Comment: The CF maven plugin has a configuration option for supporting self-signed SSL certificates. See https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-java-client/tree/1.x/cloudfoundry-maven-plugin#self-signed-ssl-certificates.

Comment: Thank you ! That did it.

Comment: Have you tried to install CA cert for your self-signed cert to garden/warden containers and machine with client?